# How to start the same action multiple times from the same startingDestination using navigation graph?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation, android-navigation-graph

I started recently using the navigation graph and i have a problem that i havent solved yet. I want to open the same fragment multiple times that they are stacked on each other. I already figured out that i need Dialogfragment because otherwise the graph is doing a replace instead of add.

The problem is that i can call the action only once. When i try to call the same action twice i the app crashes:
`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Navigation action/destination com.graphexample:id/action_add_fragment_2 cannot be found from the current destination Destination...`

My Graph:

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph_stack"
    app:startDestination="@id/fragment_1">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_1"
        android:name="com.graphexample.view.Fragment1"
        android:label="fragment_label_1"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_1" >
        <action
        android:id="@+id/action_stack_fragment_2"
            app:destination="@id/fragment_2">
        </action>
    </fragment>

    <dialog
        android:id="@+id/fragment_2"
        android:name="com.graphexample.view.Fragment2"
        android:label="fragment_label_2"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_2">
    </dialog>
</navigation>
```

The Code in Fragment1:

```
  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        (0..9).forEach {
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_stack_fragment_2)
        }
    }
```

When i try the same without the graph it works as intended:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    (0..9).forEach { i ->
        Fragment2().show(requireActivity().supportFragmentManager, "$i")
    }

}
```

Is there any way to archive startin the same activity multiple times from the same source using the navigation graph or do i have use the old way?

Comment: For what purpose are you doing this?

Comment: I don't know what your use case is but I had the same one few months back, and I also had to it without the navigation graph. As you can not trigger the navigation of a child fragment from another child fragment.
Using DialogFragment with navigation graph does gives you an ease to navigate but doing it manually is still just fine. So as long as it is doing the job, there is no worries.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using self-action.

```
<action
            android:id="@+id/action_ fragment_2_self"
            app:destination="@id/fragment_2" />
```

Comment: This wont work because fragment2 should not know about the other fragments on its level. fragment1 holds the information about how many fragments are needed on the stack.